# How can I fix this error in my python program?

Tags: python, variables, reference

Hi i'm new to python and I was trying to make an adventure game, I got to the first "random" encounter with another player and I can't seem to get it to work I keep getting the following error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'PL1ST' referenced before assignment" I am unaware of what the error means could somebody please let me know? And preferably how to prevent it, the code the error came from is here

```
if PL1ST == PLA2ST:
    print "Your warriors are equally strong!"
elif PL1SK == PLA2SK:
    print "Your warriors are equally skilled!"
elif PL1ST == PLA2ST and PL1SK == PLA2SK:
    print "Your warriors are completely equal!"
elif PL1ST > PLA2ST:
    print char1,"is stronger than",char2 ,"!"
    print char2, "has lost!"
elif PLA2ST > PL1ST:
    print char2,"is stronger than",char1 ,"!"
    PL1ST == PL1ST - PLA2ST
elif PL1SK > PLA2SK:
    print char1,"is more skilled than",char2 ,"!"
elif PL1SK < PLA2SK:
    print char2,"is more skilled than",char1 ,"!"
elif PL1SK <= 0:
    print char1, "is out of skill!"
    PL1SK == 0 
elif PLA2SK <= 0:
    print char2, "is out of skill!"
    PLA2SK == 0
```

Comment: You're trying to use the value of the variable PL1ST, but PL1ST hasn't been given a value at any point. You'll need to assign a value to this variable somewhere before you can use it.

Comment: Try deleting code until the error goes away, then add back in code until it reappears. Then post a smaller example. I imagine you could reduce this to the first two lines.

Comment: Just like @ChrisArena stated, you need to assign, at the very least, default values to your variables, something like `PL1ST = None` or something.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisArena I have done what you said and it now works :)